# JQuery Mobile Detected if there's internet Connection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, internet-connection

What is the best way to detect if there's internet connection or not on my mobile via my web app?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no code necessary for this -- it's part of the HTML5 API.  Check the value of `window.navigator.onLine` -- it will be `false` if the user is offline.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#browser-state

Comment: This give me status as online even if I am offline.

`<body onload='updateIndicator()'
       ononline='updateIndicator()' 
       onoffline='updateIndicator()'>
       <!--Check internet Connection  -->
       <script><br/>
           function updateIndicator() {
               document.getElementById('indicator').textContent = 
                    navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
           }
 </script>
 <p>The network is: <span id="indicator">(state unknown)</span>
</body>`


I tried to do formatting but could not :(

Comment: try this : function hasConnection() {
        if (window.navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 4):

An option might be [changing the Ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) to add a specific `timeout`, then add an `error` handler that looks for a `textStatus` (second argument) of `'timeout'`.

When a timeout occurs, either internet connectivity is spotty or your site is down.

---

Using [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) to set option defaults for all requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 1, // Microseconds, for the laughs.  Guaranteed timeout.
    error: function(request, status, maybe_an_exception_object) {
        if(status != 'timeout')
            alert("YOU BROKE IT");
        else
            alert("OH NOES TEH INTARWEBS ARE DOWN!!!!!1one");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Satch, I have used the links I provided to assemble a functional but not-too-useful example for you.  **I highly suggest referring to the documentation if you wish to learn more**, as everything I did here was based purely on the documentation and the description I provided of the task required.

Comment: This doesn't really work. The answer with window.navigator.onLine is the correct one.

Comment: @Satch3000 can you show me any working example? or how can we implement centrally?

Answer (score 2):

in simple JS  code this can done, causation all featured devices not have JS supported
however for web-based application this is very minimum code to use

```
online = window.navigator.onLine;
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('you are online');
} else {
  alert('you are offline');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check every X seconds the connection.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function(){
                var isOnline = navigator.onLine;
                if (isOnline) {
                    console.log("Connected");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Not Connected");
                }
            }, 30000); // 10000 = 10 seconds, check for connection every 30 seconds
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want something with more compatibility, reliability and customisability than window.navigator.onLine, try my jQuery plugin: http://tomriley.net/blog/archives/111