# Detect internet connection in cross browser platform

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to detect internet connection in my js file. i used Navigator.Online but it is not reliable especially in the Firefox and Safari.
Only chrome seems to return right output. I also came across wonderful jquery plugin checkNet but after analyzing it, i found it is only checking for server not for internet because when i run it in local it checks it from xammp server

this are the links which i used for reference

http://tomriley.net/blog/archives/111
[Check if Internet Connection Exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript)
[Jquery Plugin for Detecting Internet Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945759/jquery-plugin-for-detecting-internet-connection)

Is there other easy way to check internet connection using jquery/Java script in all browsers. I need to check the internet connection not the server error and i am also dealing with cross domain i.e. data is passed between two different domains/servers

here is navigator online code which i used but it does not seems to work perfectly

```
var netCheck = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
```

any thing jquery, javascript or PHP solution will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to ping some address, thinking outside the box ;)

Comment: I guess this is the best/robust method to find out online/offline connection. No idea why it got -1.

Comment: how do you ping using javascript or jquery ??
can u share some code??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript