# Way to check internet connectivity using javascript on hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on my personal project, which is a hybrid application developed using Ionic framework. And my application is solely dependent on internet connection.

How can I check if mobile has internet connectivity or not, via app?

Use Case: if there is no internet connection, app will display alert.

I dont want to use any 3rd party plugin, like `cordova-plugin-network-information`

Is there any solid possible way to check internet connectivity without leveraging 3rd party addons/plugin and just using JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking internet connection using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293524/checking-internet-connection-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Internet Connection Exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript)

Comment: These are more inclined for web browser, I want for mobile apps scenarios

Comment: Please explain specifically what you think they are doing browser specific that you cannot do from a mobile device.

Comment: I dont want to use jQuery!

Comment: _And my application is solely dependent on internet connection_ to do what? Download scripts or connect to an API?

Comment: Yes connect to APIs!

Comment: Create an empty action on your API to return the status code 204 (empty), if you get the response, you're online! If you don't you're not online. Or if you're using a third party API you can use the smallest GET action they have.

Comment: And why using pure Javascript function `navigator.onLine` doesn't help you?

Comment: Thanks George, but this will fail if my server is down/unreachable and I still have internet connection on device. I am using Ionic v1.

Comment: @Andy If your server is down you'll have problems anyway :)

Comment: Thanks @Laura, I just tried   
if(navigator.onLine) { console.log('User is Online'); } else { console.log('User is Offline'); } I always get 'User is Online' even when wifi is switched off on my laptop.

Comment: Why not set up a small GitHub page with some text and query it with AJAX? If it returns the text, you're online. If you want to make sure it's not just GitHub being down, do the same thing with another site, maybe CodePen, and see if both get returned.

Comment: you can use this plugin, im using this on an application i work for https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information. There is also an on offline event to make use of

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Network`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/) plugin from Ionic Native. It is designed exectly for such use cases.