# How to display a message if error occurs (say no internet connection) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-console

I need to display some message to refresh the page or try again later if there is a server communication problem, no internet connection, or ajax request did not respond, etc. And I can find all theses error messages on the console. How can I trigger a message for these?

something like this. Google's Gmail have also something similar.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `$.ajax()` function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check Internet connectivity with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043215/check-internet-connectivity-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Check Internet connectivity with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043215/check-internet-connectivity-with-jquery)

In this part of the code

```
check_connectivity.is_internet_connected().done(function() {
    //The resource is accessible - you are **probably** online.
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(0,"oops","No Internet Connection");
});
```

Of course you can replace `alert()` with whatever styling you want and display it as such.