# How to detect Internet Unavailable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When my application url load in browser, if internet is unavailable i need alert message or any error prompt show to user that 'Internet unavailable'.If internet is available it run the application. Please anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043215/check-internet-connectivity-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to write interceptor, and check it there

```
if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
 // youre code
}
```