# Check if browser is online/Internet connection (without plugins)

Tags: javascript

I need a script to check if the browser is online or not.

`navigator.onLine` doesn't really tell you if the browser is online, it just tells you if there's a network.

I've seen some plugins like:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-online

By I need to do it without installing third party plugins.

I see that the above plugin uses this URL:

```
http://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html
```

Which returns "***success***" if you're online.

How can I do this without installing and plugins?

Comment: request a resource online and if it comes back, than you have internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Internet Connection Exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384167/check-if-internet-connection-exists-with-javascript)

Comment: It's a few dozen lines of JS; even if you didn't just check a request for success/failure, I bet you could duplicate the functionality you need.

Comment: another possible duplicate with a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043215/check-internet-connectivity-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following code inside an `interval` and get your own online checker.

```
let online = 0;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/path/to/page/in/internet/or/in/your/site",
    success: function (msg) {
        online = 1;
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        online = -1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Better to suggest a callback/etc. instead of relying on a global, which would lead to a need to poll, timeout, etc. But it's a dupe question anyway.